# How can convert a string 16 characters long and with decimal to Number

Tags: javascript, typescript, numbers, vuejs3, decimal

I have a string that represents a number `2.882.956.766.235.065,23`.

I would like it to convert to `2882956766235065.23` but for string with a shorter length everything is fine, with strings of the same length or longer the part after 16 characters is cut off like this `2882956766235065`

I'm working with vue3 and typescript

this is my method

```
export function convertToNumber(value: number | string) {  
    return Number(String(value).replaceAll('.', '').replaceAll(',', '.'));
}
```

Comment: For a floating point number that large you would need to use the built-in BigInt type and massage the floating point value yourself. Thankfully there's already an open-source class written to do this for you named `BigDecimal`. See the duplicate for more information.